# How to set first page generated by MPDF as landscape

Tags: php, mpdf

Assuming you know how to use MPDF library in PHP, here's my code to instantiate an object of the class:

```
....
$marginFooter = 10;
$orientation = 'landscape';
$mpdf = new mPDF('en-x','A4','','',$marginLeft, $marginRight, $marginTop, $marginBottom, $marginHeader, $marginFooter, $orientation);
....
```

The first page of the PDF generated is still **portrait**. Even adding this line below the above code doesn't help:

```
$mpdf->DefOrientation = 'landscape';
```

If I add this tag as first tag in the body of HTML for PDF:

```
<body>
<pagebreak orientation="landscape"></pagebreak>
</body>
```

The first page is blank and portrait; and the second one is landscape.

How do I make first page **landscape**?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version you are using. But with version: ≥ 7.0 use value 'P' or 'L' as your orientation like so:

```php
    $marginFooter = 10;
    $orientation = 'L';
    $mpdf = new mPDF('en-x','A4','','',$marginLeft, $marginRight, $marginTop, $marginBottom, $marginHeader, $marginFooter, $orientation);
```

From the docs:

> **orientation**
>
> This attribute specifies the default page orientation of
> the new document if format is defined as an array. This value will be
> ignored if format is a string value.
>
> Default value: 'P'
>
> Values (case-insensitive)
>
> 'P': Portrait
>
> 'L': Landscape

Reference:

https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/construct.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have 3-4 years old version of MPDF. I have downloaded version 7.3.0 and unzipped it. Which file should I include from its folder to use it on Windows OS?

Comment: I do not know what files you need. Have you tried the P and L in your version?

Comment: Then try to get the newer version working. Or search for the documentation belonging to your version. Not sure.